# Flow type relay's createFragmentContainer

Tags: reactjs, types, flowtype, relaymodern

I'm pretty much out of ideas how to flow type relay's modern createFragmentContainer.

I got this:

```
import { type RelayContext } from 'react-relay'

type Props = {
  relay: RelayContext
}
```

`relay` is prop added by container.

Component is exported this way:

```
export default createFragmentContainer(
  Foo,
  graphql`
    fragment Foo_session on Session {
      foo {
        id
      }
    }
  `
)
```

When I use this component in some other component (e.g. like this `<Foo session={session} />`), I'll get this error:

`Flow: Cannot create 'Foo' element because property 'relay' is missing in props [1] but exists in 'Props' [2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Boris You don't have the `relay` prop on your fragment container, only on the parent, which is where you will spread this query. There, you will have the `relay` prop and you type it.

For the `Foo` component, you could type the incoming data, which will be passed from the parent. For example:

```
export default createFragmentContainer(
  Foo,
  session: graphql`
    fragment Foo_session on Session {
      foo {
        id
      }
    }
  `
)
```

you have a `__generated__` folder with the compiled query right? So you could:

```
import type { Foo_session } from './__generated__/Foo_session.graphql';

type Props = {
  session: Foo_session
}
```

Hope it helps :).

Comment: Thank you, but I actually use relay prop in this fragment because I need to call mutation in this component ( `this.props.relay.environment` ). I just don't know how to teach flow that relay prop is added by `createFragmentContainer`, not passed by parent

Comment: @Boris, not sure if I got it, but you don't need to pass `relay` to a child component to call a mutation. You can just import the mutation and run it.
Either way, are you sure that you passing it right? Because the error message it's not about a wrong typing, but the prop is not there at all.

Comment: I know that I don't need it to pass from parent, because createFragmentContainer is adding that prop to component. But when I define it in component's props, flow expects me to pass it to that component from his parent. I just don't how to flow type this: 

https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/fragment-container.html#available-props

"The Component resulting from createFragmentContainer will receive the following props"